# limit of recursively given seqeuence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let  $0 < a < b$.

A seqeunce $x_n$ satisfying $x_1 = b$ , $x_{2n} = \frac{x_n + a}{2}$, $x_{2n+1} = \frac{x_n + \sqrt{a\,x_n} + a}{3}$.

Consider if $\{x_n\}$ converges and if yes, find a limit.

As I can see, $x_2 = \frac{b+a}{2}<b$  and  $x_3=\frac{b+\sqrt{ab}+a}{3}<b$ so I assume that $x_n$  is monotonously decreasing and bounded from above but have no idea about the limit of $x_n$ itself.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly shown that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded above by b.

Can you show that it is bounded below as well?

To find the value it converges to, we assume that it converges to a value $x$, say.

Then $x_{2n}=x_{2n+1}=x$

$\frac{x+a}2=/frac{x+\sqrt{ax}+a}3$

$3(x+a)=2(x+\sqrt{ax}+a)$

$3x+3a=2x+2\sqrt{ax}+2a$

$x+a=2\sqrt{ax}$

$(x+a)^2=4ax$

$x^2+2ax+a^2=4ax$

$x^2-2ax+a^2=0$

$(x-a)^2=0$

$x=a$